# Перевод отрицательного числа из двоичной в десятичную систему

Tags: java, binary

Всем здравствуйте, есть вопрос по поводу теории с переводом отрицательного числа из двоичной в десятичную кто то может объяснить это ?
Столкнулся с этим вот на этом примере ...

```
System.out.println((byte)(127 << 1)); // 0111_1111 -> 1111_1110 -> ? (тут получается -2 но как ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно почитать как отрицательные числа представлены в двоичной форме. Грубо говоря есть в двоичной записи старший бит который отвечает за знак. Вы как раз поставили этот бит. Вот статья на эту тему где объясняют про [дополнительный код](https://www.google.com/amp/s/inf1.info/additionalcode)

Вот часть статьи:

> В дополнительном коде, также как и прямом, первый разряд отводится для
> представления знака числа. Прямой код используется для представления
> положительных чисел, а дополнительный – для представления
> отрицательных. Поэтому, если в первом разряде находится 1, то мы имеем
> дело с дополнительным кодом и с отрицательным числом.
>
> Все остальные разряды числа в дополнительном коде сначала
> инвертируются, т.е. заменяются противоположными (0 на 1, а 1 на 0).
> Например, если 1 0001100 – это прямой код числа, то при формировании
> его дополнительного кода, сначала надо заменить нули на единицы, а
> единицы на нули, кроме первого разряда. Получаем 1 1110011. Но это еще
> не окончательный вид дополнительного кода числа.
>
> Далее следует прибавить единицу к получившемуся инверсией числу:
>
> 1 1110011 + 1 = 1 1110100
>
> В итоге и получается число, которое принято называть дополнительным
> кодом числа.

Comment: Вы говорите ... Например, если 1 0001100 – это прямой код числа
а ранее сказали Поэтому, если в первом разряде находится 1, то мы имеем дело с дополнительным кодом ?

Comment: @Dimka откройте ссылку, там все расписано на примерах, до конца прочитайте и все станет ясно

Answer (score 0):

Старший бит числа отвечает за знак. Если он равен 0, то число - положительное, если 1 - отрицательное. В данном случае при сдвиге получили старший бит равным 1, значит, число получается отрицательным. Для того, чтобы получить представление этого числа в десятеричной СС, нам нужно инвертировать все биты полученного числа и добавить 1, то есть, из 11111110 получим 00000010. Итого получаем -2. Это происходит потому, что отрицательные числа в Java хранятся в так называемом дополнительном коде. Например, если мы захотим сделать число -2, то мы сначала получим его двоичное представление - 00000010, затем точно так же инвертируем его биты и добавим 1 - получим 11111110.

Comment: Подскажите а разве нужно добавлять а не вычитать 1 ?
Т. е.  1111_1110 -> -1 -> инвертировать это будет не верно ?

Comment: а ещё я так понимаю вы имели в виду что старший бит будет равен 1 ... получим 10000010.
а у вас 00000010.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что старший бит равен 1 у того числа, которое мы получили в результате битового сдвига влево на одну позицию числа 127.  Это то число, которое у вас права от стрелочки "->" в комментарии - "1111_1110". Для него мы просто инвертируем все биты, получая "0000_0001", и дальше по правилам сложения для двоичных чисел добавляем 1. Получаем "0000_0010". Итого -2.

Comment: Получаем "0000_0010".  вы имеете в виду 1000_0010

Comment: Нет, почему же. Мы сначала инвертировали все биты, получили "0000_0001", старший бит нулём, затем по правилам сложения добавили единицу и получили именно "0000_0010". Почему вы считаете, что при этом старший бит сам по себе ещё и меняется на единицу?

Comment: так тогда запись "0000_0010" в десятичном формате должна быть не минус 2 а просто 2

Comment: Не знаю, насколько строго я объясняю с точки зрения информатики, но, в принципе, "0000_0010" - это и правда просто 2. Но смотря как мы его получили. Если вы у меня просто спросите "Чему равно 00000010?", то я вам отвечу "2". Но ведь мы его получили в результате "манипуляций" над заведомо отрицательным числом, то есть, мы совершенно точно знаем, что наш результат - отрицательный, и эта двойка тоже будет отрицательной.

Comment: немного не понимаю причём тут заведомо... 1111_1110 у нас есть число у которого старший бит это 1 мы инвертируем всё включая и сам старший бит  следовательно получаем 0000_0001 а теперь добавляем 1 и получаем 00000010 объясните как тут может получится -2 если старший бит тут 0 ?